# Using JS/AJAX to do a live filter on data in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to build a live search filter on my webpage using javascript. Becaus of the structure I can't use datatables, and my team has agreed not to use it anyway.

Our site exists in laravel, so I'm finishing up a blade template for the page with existing javascript. We're trying to replicate the live filter by search bar that it was previously doing with angular.

The data on the page is built from the controller which builds an online order form out of php variables from another file, so my blade builds the data by doing foreach loops around product groups and then product skus/items in order to build tables shown in this screenshot:
[image]

So if you look at the image and the blade, you can see that my foreach around the groups builds the div with the bold name and number, as well as the description. I then have a foreach that builds the table header for the individual products and the loop inserts the products into the table (i.e. sofa, chair, etc.).

So, I'm trying to find the best way to use the search bar (code below) to do a live filter on this data. For instance, if I'm on the page of the screenshot and I start typing 'Ava', the bradshaw info should all disappear, leaving only the Ava info on the page. A live/real-time filter as the search is filled. There is no submit button so it has to be live filtering.

Below is the code for the search bar, the blade body and I have a block of javascript to get me started but it's not doing any live filtering at all. I've never really used ajax before so I don't think it's working because I'm not sure I've done the ajax call right. My console shows 404 errors everytime I type a character but I'm not sure I should be searching by URL, that's just how the code was suggested. However, I just want to filter the live data on the page, not by URL.

How can I refactor this JS to get the live filter I"m looking for? I'm thinking I may need to use a JSON object, which I have established in my JS below.

Search bar (Different div apart from table body)

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper search-form">
    <form id="searchProducts">
      <input type="text" class="md-input label-fixed" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" autofocus placeholder="Search Products"/>
       <span class="md-input-bar"></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

HTML/Blade Body:

```
@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
        <!-- <input type='hidden' name='search' value='{{ x.search }}' > -->
        <h3 style="font-size: 26px; padding: 10px 0;">{{ $pgroup->group_name }} - {{ $pgroup->group_code }}</h3>
        <p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" >{!! html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc) !!}</p> <!--Group Description-->

        <div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 100%;">
                    @foreach ($pgroup->image_names as $image_name)
                    <li><a href="/imagelib/Bigthumbs/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" target=_blank><img src=/imagelib/Bigthumbs/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a><span class="uk-text-center" style="padding: 0 0 5px;">{{ substr($image_name, strpos( $image_name, ',') + 1)  }}</span></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-width-8-10">
                <table class="uk-table" style="width: 100%; min-width: 768px;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10%; font-size: 20px;">Frame</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%; font-size: 20px;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px;">Cover/Color</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px;">Cover/Color</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%; font-size: 20px;">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;"><b>Price</b></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    @foreach ($pgroup->pskus as $psku)
                    <?php $tempdata['sku-' . $i] = $psku ?>
                    <tr class="@if (isset($psku->quantity) && $psku->quantity > 0) {{ highlight }} @endif">
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->frame_fmt }}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{!! html_entity_decode($psku->frame_desc) !!}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->cover1_code }}/{{ $psku->color1_code }} {{ $psku->color1_desc }}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->cover2_code }}/{{ $psku->color2_code }} {{ $psku->color2_desc }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="incrementer">
                              <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
                              <input onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" type="text" class="quantity-input md-input" id="sku-{{ $i }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='@if (isset($psku->quantity)) {{ $psku->quantity }} @else 0 @endif' />
                              <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 700; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; display: block; width: 100%;">${{ $psku->price }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @if ($psku->avail_date)
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: 700;">Available Date:</td>
                        <td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('dmY', $psku->avail_date)->toDateString() }}

                    </tr>
                    @endif
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
@endforeach
```

Javascript (function not working):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var orderFormData = <?php echo json_encode ($tempdata);?>;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#srch-term").on('keyup', function(){
    $search = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{{ URL::to("search") }}',
            data: {'search': $search},
            success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
            }

     });
 });
});
}
```

UPDATE:

FIddle with other JS, no ajax, and gives idea of the structure

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Do you have really to recreate this functionality ?

Comment: Yes, angular has been completely removed from our site and our users expect the search

Comment: What do you mean "Because of the structure I can't use datatables"? It sounds like you're trying to rewrite datatables, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Datatables adds a search/filter to each table and my page is built of multiple tables. I have one existing and highly formatted search bar that exists as a div at the top of the page and I need to use that search bar. Unless there's a way to make that search preform as a datatable for all of the tables on my page. You can see from the structure of my blade (looping to create a table from each group) that datatables wouldn't work for it

Comment: "Unless there's a way to make that search preform as a datatable for all of the tables on my page." Yes, this is possible and sounds much easier to do.

Comment: Ok that's what I'm unsure of. I was told an ajax request might be easiest, but the difficulty is the fact that I have a separated search that I need to use in order to display only the tables that correspond to the search input

Comment: @bassxzero do you have a suggestion on the best route to do so?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki do you have any suggestions using either AJAX or just JS? I'm incredibly desparate here and can't seem to find a good solution

Comment: We can't help that way, the first think to do is to make a fiddle containing just your HTML/CSS/JS code so we could take a real look...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ here is a fiddle of some other code I've tried, no AJAX just JS

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki is that fiddle helpful for an alternative solution? If I could even get some functionality I could play with it to get the right data

Comment: Where is the fiddle ?

Comment: I pasted into my question and my comment above